# Euclidean Distance between two vectors in two columns in spark data frme

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, vector, user-defined-functions, euclidean-distance

I am trying to get euclidean distance between two vectors, in different columns in a spark dataframe. i need this operation done on spark. i have spend a lot of time trying to do this, but can't figure it out.

below is an example code similar to my case.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vector, Vectors
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, types as T, functions as F

# Initialize Spark session
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("euclidian distance") \
    .getOrCreate()

# Sample data
data = [(Vectors.dense([1.0, 2.0]), Vectors.dense([3.0, 4.0])),
        (Vectors.dense([5.0, 6.0]), Vectors.dense([7.0, 8.0])),
        (Vectors.dense([9.0, 10.0]), Vectors.dense([11.0, 12.0]))]

# Create DataFrame
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["vector1", "vector2"])

# Define UDF for vector subtraction
def ed_vectors_udf(v1, v2):
  return Vectors.dense(v1).squared_distance(Vectors.dense(v2))
  # return Vectors.dense([x - y for x, y in zip(v1, v2)])

# Register UDF
# ed_vectors_udf = fn.udf(lambda v1, v2: eq_vectors(v1, v2), T.DoubleType())
spark.udf.register("ed_vectors_udf", ed_vectors_udf, T.DoubleType())

# Subtract vectors using UDF
df = df.withColumn("distance", ed_vectors_udf(fn.col('vector1'), fn.col('vector2')))

# Show DataFrame with subtraction result
df.show(5)
```

Link to google collab test:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1jQu2LFHV0mXK2mu3_sOWazMGbm49gvwi?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

Check this out:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df = (
  spark.createDataFrame([
    ([1,2], [3, 4]),
    ([5,6], [7, 8]),
    ([9,10], [11, 12])
  ], ['vector1', 'vector2'])
  .withColumn('distance', f.expr('pow(aggregate(transform(vector1, (x, i) -> pow(vector2[i] - x, 2)), cast(0 as double), (acc, x) -> acc + x), 0.5)'))
)
```

And the output is:

```
+-------+--------+------------------+                                           
|vector1| vector2|          distance|
+-------+--------+------------------+
| [1, 2]|  [3, 4]|2.8284271247461903|
| [5, 6]|  [7, 8]|2.8284271247461903|
|[9, 10]|[11, 12]|2.8284271247461903|
+-------+--------+------------------+
```

Comment: Hi, this did not work for me.

error i get:
AnalysisException: [DATATYPE_MISMATCH.UNEXPECTED_INPUT_TYPE] Cannot resolve "transform(vector1, lambdafunction(pow((vector2[i] - x), 2), x, i))" due to data type mismatch: Parameter 1 requires the "ARRAY" type, however "vector1" has the type "STRUCT<type: 

here is a link to google collab to check.
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1jQu2LFHV0mXK2mu3_sOWazMGbm49gvwi?usp=sharing

Comment: I think it's because I had defined vectors as ArrayType and you're defining them as vector type. Any chance they can be defined as ArrayType?